# html th 3 cells rowspan colspan

Tags: html, html-table

I'm not familiar with `rowspan` and `colspan` enough...

I'm trying to do that with html (maybe CSS?) :

```
------------------------------------------
|          |    Divided col    |         |
|          |___________________|         |
| Col 1    | part a  | part b  |  Col 3  |
|          |         |         |         |
------------------------------------------
|  data 1  | data 2a | data 2b |  data 3 |
```

Is this possible?
or just to use some sort of image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nUMV7/)**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Col 1</td>
        <td colspan="2">Divided col</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>part a</td>
        <td>part b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data 1</td>
        <td>data 2a</td>
        <td>data 2b</td>
        <td>data3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Im sorry. thats not working. because im using TH at the first row. http://jsfiddle.net/nUMV7/1/

Comment: `<th>` tags can replace `<td>` tags, not `<tr>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

Sure

```
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan='2'>
            COL1
        </td>
        <td colspan='2'>
            Divided col
        </td>
        <td rowspan='2'>
            Col 3
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            part a
        </td>
        <td>
            part b
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2a</td>
        <td>Data 2b</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: TNX! you were right. but since @j08691 brought working fiddle, im gonna have to mark his answer. tnx anyway. vote up+